# How do you modify this code so that it will print the input string in reversed order?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code and I don't why it doesn't print the input string in reversed order. I have specified it to print from the last character of the string to the first character with (-1,0,-1).

```
string=str(input())

for i in range(-1,0,-1):
    print(string[i],end="")
```

Comment: The `range(-1, 0, -1)` is empty.

Comment: Duplicate question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python

Comment: I modified it to range(len(string)-1,0,-1): but the first character is still missing

Comment: @YolandaHui: that's because the second parameter is *exclusive*, so you should use `-1`.

Comment: @YolandaHui try `range(len(string)-1, -1, -1)`. The last element of the range is never included, so the zero-index character won't be included

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `range(-1, 0, -1)` is *empty*. A range can not work with the fact that `-1` will result in the *last* element, since it does not know the length of the collection (here a string).

So if we convert the `range(..)` to a list, we get:

```
>>> list(range(-1, 0, -1))
[]
```

You thus need to start with `len(string)-1`, furthermore since the second parameter is *exclusive*, this should be `-1`. For example:

```
>>> string = 'foobar'
>>> list(range(len(string)-1, -1, -1))
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

So in your case we can use this like:

```
for i in range(len(string)-1, -1, -1):
    print(string[i],end="")
```

An aternative is to use `reversed(..)`, or by slcing the string:

```
for c in reversed(string):
    print(c, end='')
```

Note that you better first *generate* the full string, so for example:

```
print(string[::-1])
```

or an alternative (but less performant):

```
print(''.join(reversed(string))
```

Comment: Thanks I learned how to use reversed now, it looks like its the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Use slice notation to print the string backwards:

```
print(string[::-1])
```

The -1 is the step size and direction.

Answer (score 2):

As Willem Van Onsem pointed out, `range(-1, 0, 1)` is empty. If you're looking to print a string in reversed order, it's easier to use [string slicing](https://www.pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/):

```
print(string[::-1])
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `range` is not defined correctly, as demonstrated by:

```
for i in range(-1,0,-1):
  print(i)
```

doesn't return anything. Moreover `len(i)` returns `0`.

Just use list extended syntax here:

```
string=str(input())
print(string[::-1])
```

Comment: Small error: the second parameter should be `-1`, not `0`.

Comment: you mean in 'range' ? I just took what was in the original question to show that it doesn't work

Comment: Ah, sorry, did not got that somehow. +1.